# How to send image, title,description etc to facebook to share it on facebook using jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, facebook, text, share

I have created a facebook share button for a html div which contains an information like title, image and information. On click of facebook share button I want to send all the information (title, image , description) to facebook so that I can share it on facebook.

The code which I am using to send data to facebook is as follows :

```
   shareOnfacebook();


   function shareOnFacebook()
 {
    var facebook_message = document.URL;
    var facebook_url = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+encodeURIComponent(facebook_message);
    $('.facebook').attr('href', facebook_url);
 }
```

So far it's working fine for the title but I am not able to get image and description along with it. Can someone tell me how can I send remaining items to the facebook.  I know this question is duplicate but still I want to know how to accomplish above task using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic tags (anymore), sharer.php only takes the URL as parameter and will take the open graph tags from the shared URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Comment: ok, but how can i add new urls to the meta tags as every time i will be getting new data to share...?

Comment: you cannot use dynamic tags. just share a static url with static og tags, that´s all you can do. each url needs to have his own specific tags. not sure what you want to do with jquery either, facebook ignores javascript.

Comment: you can only use different parameters and output different og tags server side: yourdomain.com?param1=1, yourdomain.com?param1=2, ...

Comment: Also, the ability to add custom title, description, picture, etc. to link shares has been deprecated. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: that´s what i meant with "you cannot use dynamic tags anymore" ;)